# Bing API: specify both medium and large images

Tags: bing-api

I am forming a JSON request to pull images from the Bing API for a given query.  I want to get both medium and large images (exclude small).  I tried using:

Image.Filters=Style:Photo+Size:Medium

But this seems to be "and"ing them, as I get no results.  Having only one of them works fine.

How do I "or" them?

Answer (score 1):

```
&Image.Filters=Style:Photo&Image.Filters=Size:Medium
```